# SQL Wave Sequencing

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is the record list of follow table. I need a sql query turn from Figure 1 to Figure 2 in SQL 2008.

What figure 2 is doing is it sorting the Weight Desc and then go Asc after next STO value.

I'm thinking it has something that involves with Group By and % 2???

```
*Figure 1*
Item    SEL     STO      Weight 
1       ABC     A        80.00 
2       ABC     A        65.00 
3       ABC     A        50.00 
4       ABC     A        35.00 
5       ABC     A        20.00 
6       ABC     B        80.00 
7       ABC     B        65.00 
8       ABC     B        50.00 
9       ABC     B        35.00 
10      ABC     B        20.00 
11      ABC     C        80.00 
12      ABC     C        65.00 
13      ABC     C        50.00 
14      ABC     C        35.00 
15      ABC     C        20.00 
16      ABC     D        80.00 
17      ABC     D        65.00 
18      ABC     D        50.00 
19      ABC     D        35.00 
20      ABC     D        20.00
```

```
*Figure 2*
Item    SEL     STO      Weight 
1       ABC     A        80.00 
2       ABC     A        65.00 
3       ABC     A        50.00 
4       ABC     A        35.00 
5       ABC     A        20.00 
10      ABC     B        20.00 
9       ABC     B        35.00 
8       ABC     B        50.00 
7       ABC     B        65.00 
6       ABC     B        80.00 
11      ABC     C        80.00 
12      ABC     C        65.00 
13      ABC     C        50.00 
14      ABC     C        35.00 
15      ABC     C        20.00 
20      ABC     D        20.00 
19      ABC     D        35.00 
18      ABC     D        50.00 
17      ABC     D        65.00 
16      ABC     D        80.00
```

Comment: It seems like you want to change the sorting direction for every other group of STO.

Comment: Probably easiest way to do this is a union, but it will be gross.

Answer (score 2):

```
;with cte
as
(select *, dense_rank() over (order by sto) as rownum 
from #temp
)
select * from cte
order by 
rownum,
case when (rownum %2)=0  then wght  end asc,
case when (rownum %2)<>0 then wght  end desc
```

Comment: In this case, if `wght` is a numeric column, you could probably use
`case when (rownum %2)=0 then wght else -wght end asc` instead of the two case statements as an optimization.

Comment: Yes,that will help

Answer (score 1):

another way that requires no window functions and creates a simpler execution plan:

```
SELECT *
FROM sampleData
ORDER BY STO, [Weight] * CASE ASCII(STO)%2 WHEN 1 THEN [Weight] ELSE -[Weight] END;
```